# Como fazer com que quando tenha falas ao mesmo tempo uma delas suba para cima em arquivoss .vtt

Tags: html, css

Eu gostaria saber se tem alguma forma de fazer com que uma das falas fique no topo quando duas falas forem ao mesmo tempo, mas não fazer isso manualmente, e sim automaticamente.

Answer (score 0):

A tecnologia atual aparentemente não consegue fazer isto automaticamente, mas é possível alinhar manualmente de forma simples (afinal serão poucos lugares para ajustar provavelmente), pode usar o parâmetro `line:`, pode usar com valor `0` ou maior, vá ajustando conforme achar necessário, segue um `.vtt` de exemplo:

```
WEBVTT

0
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:12.000
Teste

1
00:00:18.700 --> 00:00:21.500
Teste inicia em 00:18
termina em 21

2
00:00:18.700 --> 00:00:23.500 line:0
Teste inicia em 00:18
mas termina em 23

3
00:00:22.800 --> 00:00:26.800
Olá mundo!

4
00:00:29.000 --> 00:00:32.450
Tchau
```

Se achar que ficou muito no topo use `line:1`.

Aqui tem algum exemplo de como usar as legendas:

- [Como colocar legendas (subtítulos) em vídeos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197046/3635)

> Tem várias propriedades que podem ser usadas para alinhar de maneiras variadas, irei editar quando possível adicionando detalhes

Comment: Sim, eu já tinha visto isso, mas gostaria que fosse feito de forma automática, sem eu ter que revisar cada legenda

Comment: Infelizmente não tem como @LucasCarezia, creio que foi feito assim para você poder customizar como quiser as legendas.