# Como colocar legendas (subtítulos) em vídeos?

Tags: html, html5

Como posso adicionar legendas/subtitles a tag vídeo:

```html
<video>
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: amigo vi que você colocou no github, como eu pego esse link para funcionar no player? eu clico em raw mais pelo link que gera não vai... obrigado!

Comment: Olá @MuriloSilva Não coloquei no meu github, na resposta só esta o formato de exemplo, não é uma legenda real, é só para ensinar você ou qualquer um que ler a resposta a criar a sua propria legenda

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existe o formato [webvtt](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webvtt), um arquivo deve ter este formato:

```
WEBVTT

0
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:12.000
Teste

1
00:00:18.700 --> 00:00:21.500
Teste inicia em 00:18

2
00:00:22.800 --> 00:00:26.800
Olá mundo!

3
00:00:29.000 --> 00:00:32.450
Tchau
```

E salve-o em um arquivo, de preferência com a extensão `.vtt` (apesar de não afetar em nada)

O HTML deve ficar assim:

```html
<video>
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track label="Português" kind="subtitles" srclang="pt" src="legenda-portugues.vtt" default>
</video>
```

Note que isto irá funcionar em HTTP, em local não funciona (protocolo `file://`)

Os atributos:

- `label` indica para o usuário qual a legenda que esta usando de forma descritiva
- `srclang` deve ser definido quando usar o valor `subtitles` no atributo `kind`
- `src` é o caminho aonde se encontra a legenda
- `default` ativa a legenda
- `kind` aceita diversas propriedades, para legendas usamos `kind="subtitles"`

### Colocando múltiplas legendas (subtítulos)

Este é um exemplo de uso de múltiplas legendas, você pode alternar entre os idiomas

```html
<video controls>
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

    <track label="Português Brasileiro" kind="subtitles" srclang="pt-br" src="subtitle/sub-pt-br.vtt" default>
    <track label="Português Portugal" kind="subtitles" srclang="pt-pt" src="subtitle/sub-pt-pt.vtt">
    <track label="American English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en-us" src="subtitle/sub-en-us.vtt">
    <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en-gb" src="subtitle/sub-en-gb.vtt">
</video>
```

### Atributo `kind="..."`

- **subtitles**

  O subtítulos fornecem tradução de conteúdo que não pode ser compreendido pelo espectador. Por exemplo diálogo ou texto que não é inglês em um filme de língua inglesa.

  As legendas podem conter conteúdo adicional, geralmente informações de fundo extra. Por exemplo, o texto no início dos filmes Star Wars, ou a data, hora e local de uma cena.
- **captions**

  Os *"closed captions"* proporcionam uma transcrição e possivelmente uma tradução de áudio.

  Pode incluir importantes informações *não verbais*, tais como pistas de música ou efeitos sonoros. Pode indicar a fonte da sugestão (por exemplo, música, texto, caractere).

  Adequado para usuários com deficiência auditiva ou quando o som é silenciado.
- **descriptions**

  Descrição do conteúdo do vídeo, o que pode ser usado por pessoas com defiencia visual (ainda não pude testar, talvez dependa de leitores de tela)
- **chapters**

  Os títulos de capítulo são destinados a serem usados quando o usuário está navegando na vídeo.
- **metadata**

  Faixas usadas por scripts, não é visível ao usuário.

<sub>Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track</sub>