# MKV sem legenda HTML5

Tags: html, vídeo

Estou criando um site onde vai conter videos em mkv com legendas mas as legendas do vídeo não aparecem, o vídeo roda normalmente com áudio mas as legendas não aparecem. Pelo que eu vi o Chrome não roda arquivos mkv, teria algum jeito de rodar eles? Não tenho as legendas separadas por isso preciso que rode sem eu ter que embutir as legendas.

Comment: html5 usa legendas no formato [WEBVTT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197046/3635), legendas em outros formatos não funcionam.

Comment: Não teria como rodar o video no servidor e exibir ao usuario? Usando outra linguagem como python ou asp.net isso seria possivel?

Comment: Acho que você esta confundindo front-end com back-end.

Comment: Então meio que é impossível? Bom se for assim eu vou tentar converter o vídeo com o ffmpeg. Você sabe algum formato que eu consiga manter a legenda do mkv?

Comment: a não ser que a legenda na verdade seja vídeo, você não conseguirá manter, o único formato aceito no html5 é vvt, talvez exista algum programa que converta a legenda como sendo parte do vídeo (decodifica o vídeo), então assim a legenda passaria a ser parte das imagens, se você tiver o SOURCE da legenda em outro formato existem conversores que a transforma em webvvt